# Unable to get data from firebase using the first array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not able to get the email list data from firebase. All it shows is "null".

Although the variable `agent0` shows the correct selected data from the array,  I can't seem to use it with the firebase reference.

How can I use one of the array values to get data from firebase?

```
var agent0 = agents[0];
window.alert(agent0);

var refPullEmail = firebase.database().ref("Forwarder Contact").child("All Origins").child(agent0);

refPullEmail.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {

        var agentEmail_0 = snapshot.child("EmailList").val(); //return list emails

        window.alert(agentEmail_0);

    });
```

Database :

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of your database to the question

Comment: added the database all i want to get from this is the Email list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the `EmailList` try the following:

```
var refPullEmail = firebase.database().ref("Forwarder Contact").child("All Origins").child("ALLIANCE");

refPullEmail.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {

    var agentEmail_0 = snapshot.child("EmailList").val(); //return list emails

    window.alert(agentEmail_0);

});
```

The above will retrieve the `EmailList` under node `ALLIANCE`.

---

If you want to retrieve all the `EmailList` under node `All Origins`, then try the following:

```
var refPullEmail = firebase.database().ref("Forwarder Contact").child("All Origins");

refPullEmail.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){

    var agentEmail_0 = snapshot.child("EmailList").val(); //return list emails

    window.alert(agentEmail_0);

   });
});
```

Here, you iterate inside the direct children of `All Origins` and retrieve the `EmailList`.